# To copy an index from one machine to another in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have some indexes in one of my machines. I need to copy them to another machine, how can i do that in elasticsearch. 
I did get some good documentation [here](http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2015/05/20/reindex-elasticsearch-with-logstash/), but since im an newbie to elasticsearch ecosystem and since im toying with lesser data indices, I thought I would use some plugins or ways which would be less time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 3 options here

1. Snapshot/Restore - You can move your data across geographical locations.
2. Logstash reindex - As pointed out by Val
3. [Stream2ES](https://github.com/elastic/stream2es) - This is a more simpler solution

Answer (score 2):

I would use [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/index.html) with an [`elasticsearch` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html) plugin and an [`elasticsearch` output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) plugin.

After [installing Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html), you can create a configuration file `copy.conf` that looks like this:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => "localhost:9200"                     <--- source ES host
   index => "source_index"
  }
}
filter {
 mutate {
  remove_field => [ "@version", "@timestamp" ]   <--- remove added junk
 }
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
   host => "localhost"                           <--- target ES host
   port => 9200
   protocol => "http"
   manage_template => false
   index => "target_index"
   document_id => "%{id}"                        <--- name of your ID field
   workers => 1
 }
}
```

And then after setting the correct values (source/target host + source/target index), you can run this with `bin/logstash -f copy.conf`

Comment: Yes. But I was looking for something simpler without involving logstash.

Comment: Then I would recommend the other answer leveraging snapshot/restore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Snapshot and restore feature as well, where you can take snapshot (backup) of one index and then can Restore to somewhere else.

Just have a look at 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html